# Passing variable or variables in express.js from react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongodb, express, axios

I am Clicking a button on frontend and it is getting me a prompt and using that prompt I am getting the value. Now I have to pass this variable to the express.js(backend) so that I can use this variable as a name of my mongodb database collection name.

This is frontend.

```js
import { Avatar } from '@material-ui/core';
import React from 'react';
import "./SidebarChat.css";

function SidebarChat({adddNewChat}) {

    const createChat = e => {
        const roomname = prompt("Add a new chat name");

        if(roomname){
            // have to pass this roomname to the express
        }
    }

    return !adddNewChat ? (
        <div className="sidebarChat">
            <Avatar />
            <div className="sidebarChat__right">
                <h2>Room Name</h2>
                <p>Last Message</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    ) :
    (
        <div className="sidebarChat" onClick={createChat}>
            <h2> Add new Chat</h2>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SidebarChat
```

Please help how can I pass this variable so that I can use it as a collection name and make a collection in mongodb.

Comment: you should use ```axios ``` to send a post request , then in your backend handle that post request

Comment: Create a new endpoint on your express server where you will receive the "roomname" value and create the collection with mongoose. You can pass the value from React to the express endpoint with an http request.